# Database Design - Sharing Association From Super / Parent Entity

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity, relational-database

I'm having trouble determining the proper database design involving entities that may or may not have a relationship with a super entity, or parent entity.

I have the tables `work_orders`, `work_order_groups`, and `contracts` for the corresponding entities.

Originally, it started out with work orders having a `1-to-1` relationship with contracts. But the concept of child work orders was introduced, for extra work of a different type. They were still work orders, but branched from a main work order, so a `parent_work_order_id` was added to represent that relationship as a foreign key referencing the `id` of another work order. So a work order could have `0-to-1` parent work orders.

Those child work orders shared the same contract with the parent work order, thus the relationship was changed to `1-to-M` for contracts to work orders.

[image: diagram 1]

Hopefully at this point, the database design sounds acceptable. Now this is where I'm having some doubts. We've introduced a package deal, where there can be multiple work orders grouped together. We need a work order group entity to exist, so that we can record details about that group. The work orders would have a `0-to-1` relationship with the work order groups.

The contract is going to be created on details from the work order group, so I'm thinking the contract should be associated to the work order group. This would give a `1-to-1` relationship between work order groups and contracts. Similar to child work orders, all work orders within a group are going to share the same contract. And so that can cascade down to all child items: You'd have a work order group with a contract, all the work orders share that contract, and then all the child work orders too. I'm unsure about this design. In my head, I've got something like this:

[image: diagram 2]

Is this acceptable? I feel like I'm going to be storing the `contracts_id` in multiple places, although that is indeed how the relationship works out.

Answer (score 0):

0-to-1 -- Have the id (of the '0') be a valid id or `NULL` (or perhaps `0`) sitting in the Entity table for the '1'.

1:many -- In a single table ('tree'/'parent-child'/'hierarchy') -- The child record has the id of the one parent.  The ultimate ancestor (if there is such) will have a `parent` of `NULL` or `0`.  A childless parent is possible, but not obvious by looking at the parent row.

1:many -- In two tables, do something similar.